# Multiple UIWebView instances or what is it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, uiwebview

I have an app with a `UIWebView` in a `UIView`.

[URL to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnUut.png)

At this picture I see all my websites I visited. If I open `Safari` -> Developer -> Name of testing iPhone -> listed content of the picture. Are these visited sites different `UIWebView` instances?

Is my suspicious correct or what is there shown?

```
-(void)createWebView {
    //[[self webView] removeFromSuperview];
    //[[self view] willRemoveSubview:[self webView]];
    [self setWebView:[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self view] addSubview:[self webView]];
    });
    [[self webView] setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [[self webView] setDelegate:self];
```

}

webView is a variable in my `header` file of type `UIWebView` and at every new entered URL the `webview` should be overwritten every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Instance of `UIWebView` holds its own history.
General Safari history is restricted to be accessed. And even if you managed to get them, i doubt your app will be accepted by Apple review team.

So the solution i think is to create `NSMutableArray` and loop on your `UIWebViews` and add their history into a single place -your created array-.
By so you will have all your local history in that array and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can you explain me what it is at the image? I only want one `UIWebView` instance as subview on my `UIView`, so I want to remove all `web views` from my `view`. I created an `NSArray`, added the `subviews` from my `view` and  remove them with `removeFromSuperview` within a loop

Comment: you can add the history to the array by following the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13348387/1803129